# In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows so the formula have #value

Tags: spreadsheet

i'm trying to use google sheet but i have #value in my sheet, the formula is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(QUERY( {K45:L; TRIM(L45:L)}; "select Col2 where Col2 <> '' order by Col1 desc"; 1)))
```

Any Solutions??

Best Regards